# If statement done correctly?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, statements

I have to move a rover on a 10x10 hypothetic board. Everything goes smoothly until I set the if statement on moveForward(and moveBackward)function when it gives me error. With the if conditions, the player should not be able to move outside of the grid because an error message should appear, in my case the msg: You cannot place the rover outside the board!

```
let myRover = {
   direction: 'N',
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   travelLog: [{
       x: 0,
       y: 0
   }]
}


function turnLeft(rover) {

   console.log('turnLeft was called!');

   switch (rover.direction) {

       case 'W':
           rover.direction = 'S';
           break;

       case 'N':
           rover.direction = 'W';
           break;

       case 'S':
           rover.direction = 'E';
           break;

       case 'E':
           rover.direction = 'N';
           break;
   }
}

function turnRight(rover) {

   console.log('turnRight was called!');

   switch (rover.direction) {
       case 'N':
           rover.direction = 'E';
           break;

       case 'W':
           rover.direction = 'N';
           break;

       case 'S':
           rover.direction = 'W';
           break;

       case 'E':
           rover.direction = 'S';
           break;
   }
}

function moveForward(rover) {

   console.log('moveForward was called');

    if (rover.x >= 0 && rover.x < 9 && rover.y >= 0 && rover.y < 9) {

   switch (rover.direction) {

       case 'N':
           rover.x++;
           break;

       case 'W':
           rover.y--;
           break;

       case 'S':
           rover.x--;
           break;

       case 'E':
           rover.y++;
           break;
   }
  } else {
     console.log(''You cannot place the rover outside the board!'');
    } 

}

//print out rover position

console.log(`The rover has position: x= ${rover.x} ,  y= ${rover.y};`)

//declare a new variable in order to update and push the new position into our roverObject

let newPosition = {
   x: rover.x,
   y: rover.y
};

rover.travelLog.push(newPosition);


function moveBackward(rover) {

   console.log('moveBackward was called');

    if (rover.x >= 0 && rover.x < 9 && rover.y >= 0 && rover.y < 9) {

     switch (rover.direction) {

       case 'N':
           rover.x--;
           break;

       case 'W':
           rover.y++;
           break;

       case 'S':
           rover.x++;
           break;

       case 'E':
           rover.y--;
           break;
   }
    } else {
   console.log(''You cannot place the rover outside the board!'');
   check }

   rover.travelLog.push(newPosition);

}

//print out rover position 

console.log(`The rover has position: x= ${rover.x} ,  y= ${rover.y};`)

//create a function that receives a list of commands (what the rover should do when we give it certain commands)

function command(rover, orders) {
   for (let i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
       let order = orders[i];

       switch (order) {

           case 'f':
               moveForward(rover, order);
               break;

           case 'r':
               turnRight(rover, order);
               break;

           case 'l':
               turnLeft(rover, order);
               break;

           case 'b':
               moveBackward(rover, order);
               break;

/*BONUS 3// If we enter a letter into our input that is not one of the rover commands, nothing will happen    
               // check  default:
               // check continue; */

       }
   }

   console.log(`The rover path was: ${rover.travelLog});

}
```

Comment: `console.log(''You cannot place the rover outside the board!'');` - this is wrong. If you want to use double quotes you have to use the `"` symbol, not two apostrophes `''`. Or you can just use single quotes for the string.

Comment: You are checking if the rover is outside only *after* moving the rover.

Comment: "when it gives me error" - just to be clear, what exactly is the error please? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of irrelevant functions. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You have just one `newPosition` object, and you keep pushing that same object to the travelLog. That is not going to do anything useful.

Comment: Would it be better if you split the if tests into separate ones for x and y?  At present, if someone is in x=0 and y=0, the code will still allow them to move as you have ">=0" in the tests.  Assuming that x is horizontal, then being in position 0 means that they should only be able to move right or if they are in position 9, then they should only be able to move left.  So, you might even want to first check what direction they want to move and THEN check where they are moving from and if the move is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are currently checking the current position, they should instead be checking the future position of the rover. So for example:

```
function moveBackward(rover) {
     console.log('moveBackward was called');
     let future_x = rover.x
     let future_y = rover.y
    

     switch (rover.direction) {
       case 'N':
           future_x--;
           break;

       case 'W':
           future_y++;
           break;

       case 'S':
           future_x++;
           break;

       case 'E':
           future_y--;
           break;
   }
   
   if (future_x >= 0 && future_x <= 9 && future_y >= 0 && future_y <= 9) {
      rover.x = future_x
      rover.y = future_y
      rover.travelLog.push(newPosition);
   } else {
       console.log("You cannot place the rover outside the board!");
   }
}
```

Comment: given that this is a 10x10 grid, then the valid positions should 0-9 - do you need to change < 9 to <= 9 ??

Comment: Good catch, I didn't pay attention to the condition in the if statement

Comment: :)  I tend to think of things the other way around from this.  ie, if the future position is < 0 or > 9 then don't allow the move.  But, the result is the same, I guess!

Comment: not to mention that the condition can be rewritten as `if ([future_x, future_y].every(x => x >= 0 && x <= 9))`

Comment: Now you're getting fancy with your code!  Having said that, I would simply disable their ability to move in a direction that would move them outside of the board by either hiding the button they click or ignoring a left/right/up/down button press, depending on how movements are made.